# How to get All users list from keycloak using Dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, keycloak

We have created one POC application for our local purpose. Application created in .NET Core MVC template. I need to get all users list from `keycloak` based on realm name, but I don't know how to get all users list from keycloak. Please help me.

```
"keycloak": {
    "Authority": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/KeycloakMVCDemo",
    "ClientId": "mvcdemo",
    "ClientSecret": "c035ee7c-2e10-43b0-a63c-c9137580b630"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: you should not show your secret here in public :)

Try that:

First you need to get a token:

```
var client =
                new RestClient(
                    "https://yourkeycloak.de/auth/realms/yourrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddParameter("client_id", "XXXXX");
            request.AddParameter("client_secret", "XXXX");
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
          
            var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OAuthResponse>(response.Content).access_token;
```

Than you can use the api to get all users from a realm

```
var client = new RestClient("https://yourkeycloak.de/auth/admin/realms/yourrealname/users");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

To get the users from the response you could deserialize the response like that:

```
var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserRoot[]>(response.Content);
```

Here are the classes that you need to deserialze the response:

```
 public class UserRoot
    {
        public User[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public long createdTimestamp { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public bool enabled { get; set; }
        public bool totp { get; set; }
        public bool emailVerified { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public object[] disableableCredentialTypes { get; set; }
        public object[] requiredActions { get; set; }
        public int notBefore { get; set; }
        public Access access { get; set; }
      
    }

    public class Access
    {
        public bool manageGroupMembership { get; set; }
        public bool view { get; set; }
        public bool mapRoles { get; set; }
        public bool impersonate { get; set; }
        public bool manage { get; set; }
    }
```

And the struct for the OAuthResponse:

```
public struct OAuthResponse
    {
        public string access_token;
        public int expires_in;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I tried the above method but its not working. token returns null value.

Comment: Ok i tried it with success just before. are you sure you use the correct config data like url clientid and secret? and have you put your keycloak data in the url for the domain and the realm?